# Tomcat installation on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have recently installed tomcat on my Ubuntu.It running successfully by using url :
http://localhost:8080/ in browser.

But I am not getting its auto deploy folder.I want to know about value of $CATALINA_HOME
Kindly tell me if there is any command to know about root directory for tomcat.How I can
know path in $CATALINA_HOME

Thanks

Deepak

Comment: This belongs either on ServerFault or AskUbuntu

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a [good wiki article describing usage of Apache Tomcat](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/tomcat.html). If you are using the "system-wide installation" option you might find the webapps folder at either `/var/lib/tomcat6` or `/usr/share/tomcat6` IIRC.

If you are using Tomcat as development container, it might be more practical to use non-privileged instances as described in section "Using private instances" (in the wiki article) or simply download and unzip a binary distribution from http://tomcat.apache.org in a custom directory and use that one instead.